# (win/linux) Text editor with good regex support

Tags: regex, linux, window, text-editor

I'm looking for a text editor in win7/ubuntu which has good regex support.  I've tried a few which have partial support or seem to use a custom syntax, so I'm looking for a program which has full support and no/little custom style regex.  For example, I'm trying to execute the following exp against some text:

^((?!test).)*$

to find lines without the word test in.  I've tested this in various online tools and I think the reg exp is sound, but i can't find a text editor which I can use/trust.

Comment: Don't you feel that `(?!...)` is also custom style?

Comment: It could be, but I was under the impression that it wasn't - I guess it depends on where you look!  Is there a definitive regex syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim has regex support but the pattern syntax is a bit different:

```
/\(\(test\)\@!.\)*$
```

You can make it less obscure by turning on the verymagic setting:

```
/\v((test)@!.)*$
```

read `:help pattern`.

Also note that this pattern matches `est` and following characters just after the last occurrence of `test` on a line, or whole lines containing no occurrence of `test`. Is that what you want?

**If you don't know vim, you should probably start with `vimtutor`.** Vim is not designed for user friendliness, and has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to match the entire word, not a subset of the characters.  I've used vi before, but not the regex part - will have a look, but don't suppose you know how i could get it to look for the whole word?

Comment: @Martyn: Yes: `.*\zs\<test\>.*`. `\zs` marks start of match, `\<` and `\>` are word delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

Vim has support for that type of negative lookahead, even though the syntax is different.

See here:

- http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/vim/searching.html